# SocialAuth java library working with google account

Tags: java, authentication, socialauth

I'm facing an issue in socialAuth java library. I used that library for logging to my app by using social networks. Login with Facebook is working properly. But when i try to use google and yahoo is does not work for me. Error occur when after authentication process, redirection part is not working properly,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@RequestMapping(params = "code")
private String oauth2Callback(final HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response,
                              Model model) throws Exception {
    String serviceReturnUrl = request.getParameter("service");
    String clientAppKey = request.getParameter("app_key");
    org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider provider = null;
    SocialAuthManager manager = socialAuthTemplate.getSocialAuthManager();
    if (manager != null) {
        try {
            provider = manager.connect(SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap(request));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(appLoadConfigurer.getProperty("caslk"));
        return "";
    }
```

When redirecting Facebook to my app this method catch the request. but when it comes to google, i could not catch the request from google by using this method. request is not comes to here. Any one can idea to fix my issue as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

For google you will have to use

```
@RequestMapping(params = "openid.claimed_id")
```

Because google doen't return any attribute with name 'code' that's why it is not matching with this.